# NWJS- node-webkit emit events from Window objects

Tags: javascript, events, node-webkit, eventemitter, nwjs

The [documentation](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/) of NWJS says that Window inherits EventEmitter, no normally I should be able to use  `emit()` from a Window object but it doesn't work and i'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined nwjs
```

but the doc says...

> Every Window is an instance of the EventEmitter class, and you’re able
>   to use Window.on(...) to respond to native window’s events.

here's my code...

```
var GUI= require('nw.gui');
   var WIN= GUI.Window.get();            
   gui.Window.open('live.html',{}, function(newWindow){
      newWindow.emit("test", {data:"Heyo!"});
});
```

i'm using nwjs
version 0.18
what i'm I doing wrong ?

Comment: as of [nwjs 0.13](http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Migration/From%200.12%20to%200.13/#window) - *Window is not inherited from EventEmitter anymore, but the methods on(), once(), removeListener() and removeAllListeners() are still supported.*

Comment: oh noo, why did they do such a thing? now how do we do

Comment: maybe the standard `dispatchEvent` ?